# ERROR: This error happened during the backup: [Errno 1] Unknown host Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: cassandra

I just did a setup for latest medusa.
Following error is seen when we take backup:

```
root@c2m:~# medusa backup --backup-name=18042020

[2020-04-18 10:58:04,329] INFO: Monitoring provider is noop

[2020-04-18 10:58:04,337] WARNING: is ccm : 0

[2020-04-18 10:58:04,423] INFO: Creating snapshot

[2020-04-18 10:58:04,423] INFO: Saving tokenmap and schema

[2020-04-18 11:06:43,616] ERROR: This error happened during the backup: [Errno 1] Unknown host
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/medusa/backup.py", line 252, in main
schema, tokenmap = get_schema_and_tokenmap(cassandra)
```

Comment: What is the snapshot status Is it created successfully?  Any error on system.log?

Comment: No error found on system.log

Comment: Snapshot created?

Comment: Snapshot created, fqdn not working according to my check.

Comment: Okay, whats fqdn?